# What effect does IgnoreStructureMapAttributes have on a StructureMap container?

Tags: structuremap

What effect does `IgnoreStructureMapAttributes()` method have on the assembly scanner?

The [documentation for IgnoreStructureMapAttributes](http://www.nudoq.org/#!/Packages/structuremap/StructureMap/IAssemblyScanner/M/IgnoreStructureMapAttributes) is sparse and doesn't state what effect the method has.

As I see it, this could have two possible effects

1. all types are registered, not just those with the StructureMap attributes.
2. all types are ignored.